# UITabBarItem font changes after the tab bar gets hidden

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have experienced a strange issue in the app where the selected tab bar colour changes from the colours I have set back to the tint colour after opening a view controller with the following option:

```
hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
```

Here is the code I have used to set the font colour prior to finding the issue inside of the initialiser of my customer `UITabBarController`:

```
let attributes = ...
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a similar issue on StackOverflow and managed to figure out the solution with the help of the team in my company, so I thought I would share it here in case it helps anybody in the future.

The only way to fix the above issue that we've managed to find is adding the following code to the initializer of our customer `UITabBarViewController`

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()

    appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    appearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
    appearance.shadowColor = UIColor.white

    let defaultAttributes = ...

    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = UIColor.red
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = defaultAttributes

    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor = UIColor.red
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = attributes

    tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
}
```